# is it possible to making a posting to Craigslist through my own website?

Tags: php, html, post, curl, craigslist

What I am trying to do is allow users to making postings to Craiglist through my own website using PHP curl. This is NOT an automated posting system, I just want users to be able to post onto Craigslist and my website at the same time. So far, I've managed to log in using php but I'm still not sure how to post the title, description, contact information, etc. I am not familiar with cURL.

I'm working with a script I found through Google:

```
<?php

// INIT CURL
$ch = curl_init();

// SET URL FOR THE POST FORM LOGIN
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.craigslist.org/');

// ENABLE HTTP POST
$email = "email";
$pass = "pass";
$url = "inputEmailHandle=".urlencode($email)."&inputPassword=".urlencode($pass);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url);

$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

ob_start(); 
curl_exec ($ch);
ob_end_clean(); // execute the curl command 

curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch);

//initialize second curl
$ch = curl_init();
//second curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://sandiego.craigslist.org/sub/');
$content = curl_exec ($ch);


echo $content;
// CLOSE CURL
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Comment: I think this violates their TOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible (it probably is), but it is against Craigslist TOS, so be careful.

> 1. POSTING AGENTS
>
> A "Posting Agent" is a third-party
>   agent, service, or intermediary that
>   offers to post Content to the Service
>   on behalf of others. To  moderate
>   demands on craigslist's resources, you
>   may not use a Posting  Agent to post
>   Content to the Service without express
>   permission or  license from
>   craigslist.  Correspondingly, Posting
>   Agents are not  permitted to post
>   Content on behalf of others, to cause
>   Content to  be so posted, or otherwise
>   access the Service to facilitate
>   posting  Content on behalf of others,
>   except with express permission or 
>   license from craigslist.

Comment: Why does everyone always cite this when craigslist themselves have developed a mechanism for automated bulk posting?  http://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface

Comment: ...because OP's code would violate the terms of service quoted here. Companies typically develop APIs so that users don't have to rely on tools like curl, which are generally frowned upon when used for these purposes. OP does not use the bulk posting method you're talking about, and thus his code is an example of a posting agent that certainly does not have the express permission of Craigslist.

Comment: Ahh.  You're right.  My apologies, I'd been searching for some help with their bulk uploading api and was getting frustrated with all of the TOS answers in response to questions people had about it.  This question obviously isn't related to their bulk uploading api.  No excuse, but I guess my frustration with the lack of documentation and help on the subject got the best of me.

Comment: Haha, you'll get a kick out of this.  I just went to upvote your answer after reading your response but couldn't because I already did on May 29th!

Comment: Ha! That's funny. No apologies necessary, just clarifying!

Comment: If he develops this for himself (or anyone else develops it for themselves) then it is not a " third-party agent, service, or intermediary" offering "to post Content to the Service on behalf of others" because he's doing it himself. If the paragraph cited above is the only paragraph addressing this, then I do not believe that the TOS would be violated by this. That's my legal opinion. :)

Comment: I think the TOS applies to non-paid accounts. The linked bulk posting interface (as they call it) is only available to paid posting accounts, which this fact I ascertained from the fact that the RSS format requires the user's account ID. From what I can tell, the account ID is only available for paid accounts.